# kubernetes Application downtime

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I have setup the kubernetes with one master and two Workers, but I am facing one issue.

I have created the apache pod; it will deployed on worker1 automatically by the scheduler. It works fine. When I stop the worker one machine, ideally pod will be generated on worker2. The problem is that it takes around 7 minutes to come online on workers2.

Is there any way to fail the pod over without any downtime?

Answer (score 2):

There will be a minor downtime unless you have multiple replicas (apache replicas) and have a Kubernetes service forwarding to them on your system. This is generally the architecture is recommended for HTTP/TCP type of services.

However, if you need faster response you could tweak:

- `--node-status-update-frequency` on the kubelet. (Default 10 seconds)
- `--kubelet-timeout` on the kube-apiserver. Which defaults to a low 5 seconds.
- `–-node-monitor-period` on the kube-controller-manager. Defaults to 5 seconds.
- `-–node-monitor-grace-period` on the kube-controller-manager. Defaults to 40 seconds.
- `-–pod-eviction-timeout` on the kube-controller-manager. Defaults to 5 minutes.

You can try something like this:

- kubelet: `--node-status-update-frequency=4s` (from 10s)
- kube-controller-manager: `--node-monitor-period=2s` (from 5s)
- kube-controller-manager: `--node-monitor-grace-period=16s` (from 40s)
- kube-controller-manager: `--pod-eviction-timeout=30s` (from 5m)

Comment: Thanks.
Got your point, means we can achieve this by replica.